How to get values reset weekly and recalculated
Here is my pine script code
//@version=4
      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      
      study(title="previous Week high & low", shorttitle="Prev Wk H-L", overlay=true, precision=8)
      
      prevwkH = input(true, title="Show previous week high?")
      prevwkL = input(true, title="show previous week low?")
      
      //previous week
      prevWeekHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, '3W', high[1], lookahead=true)
      prevWeekLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, '3W', low[1], lookahead=true)
      var float weekClose = security(syminfo.tickerid, '3W', close[1])
      
      mid = (prevWeekHigh + prevWeekLow + weekClose) / 3
      upper = mid + ((prevWeekHigh - prevWeekLow) / 2)
      lower = mid - ((prevWeekHigh - prevWeekLow) / 2)
      
      //previous Week Plots
      plot(prevwkH ? mid : na, title="mid", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=1, color=color.fuchsia, transp=20)
      plot(prevwkL ? upper : na, title="upper", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=1, color=color.fuchsia, transp=20)
      plot(prevwkL ? lower : na, title="lower", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=1, color=color.fuchsia, transp=20)

I want there to be plotted 3 lines for each week, but i feel like some value is not getting reset, and after a few weeks my lines are getting shifted, how can I fix this?
Beginning:

End:

i want lines to be precise and recalculated for each week using  3 previous weeks, but they are getting shifted as if old values are used
